# Filter text for mysql search

Tags: php, mysql, regex, filter

I am new to regex and really don't have a clue.
I have a MySql table looking like this:

```
id | grade | subject | kind | tally
1  | 11    | M       | L    | 1
2  | 11    | E       | L    | 3
3  | 11    | D       | G    | 1
4  | 11    | GK      | G    | 1
5  | 11    | SPA     | G    | 6
```

you get the idea...:)

Grade is an int, either 11,12 or 13.
Subject is a string, between 1-4 "chars" long.
Kind is either "L" or "G".
Tally is an int, between 1 and 6.

This table is supposed to hold all of the classes/lessons there are at my school.
When you write out the classname it would look something like this "11EL4" or "11ML1".

I want to be able to turn this "description" into grade, subject, kind and tally.
For example:

```
function descriptionToArray($description){
    // $grade   = regex voodoo :)
    // $subject = regex voodoo :)
    // ...

    return array("grade"=>$grade,"subject"=>$subject,...);
}
```

My guess would have been regex but I really don't know how that works (even after tutorials)

Comment: I learnt regex by reading the descrptions of the different options at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and playing around with said tool. Very efficient if you take the time to play around with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('/(11|12|13)([A-Z]{1-4})(L|G)([1-6]{1})/', $class_string, $match)) {
    list($dummy, $grade, $subject, $kind, $tally) = $match;
}
```

Explanation:

- `(11|12|13)` matches 11, 12 or 13
- `([A-Z]+?)` matches 1 or more capital letters (ungreedy)
- `(L|G)` matches an `L` or a `G`
- `([1-6]{1})` matches a single digit in the range 1-6

The `$dummy` is required because `$match[0]` will hold the entire regular expression match. Elements 1-4 will hold each patenthesised substring.

Comment: this looks pretty nice but it always returns false when I input something :(

Comment: try preg_match_all because you have more than 1 same characters in some of the lines.

Comment: I found the problem. The `([A-Z]{1,4})` is consuming the L or G following it, if it is only 1-3 characters long. I'm not sure how to fix that though. I'm looking for a solution and will update here when (if) I find one.

Comment: I fixed it. I turned the subject match into an ungreedy `([A-Z]+?)`

Answer (score 1):

Not much voodoo and kinda simple solution without regex could be:

```
function descriptionToArray($description){
    $grade = substr($description, 0, 2);
    $subject = substr($description, 2, strlen($description)-4);
    $kind = substr($description, -2, -1);
    $tally = substr($description, -1);

    return array("grade" => $grade, "subject" => $subject, "kind" => $kind, "tally" => $tally);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract grade, subject or kind in different variables to do something on those then why not use a mysql_query to get those variables.
If you want to make the classname from the data in the table, then get those variables from mysql_query and concatenate then to form your classname.
and to make it an array put those variables in the array.

example:

```
//establish the mysql connection and select the database.

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class"); //Where class is your table name

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { return array($row["grade"], $row["subject"], $row["kind"]); } 

//Then use that array for whatever you want to use it for. Also assign a variable to it to use it outside the while loop.
```

Comment: lateron I want to get the ID of a description. Example: idOfDesc("11EL3") = 2. To do this I will need the different parts...

Comment: Then use implode to form a line of all the values. Then use explode to form an array of each of the values in the string.To make this usable do it in a for or while loop and assign a variable in each of the strings and then increment to the next number for a new variable.

Comment: This would only work if every part was 1 char long. Which glue & separator would I use?... I think you missunderstood my question...

Comment: implode and explode have no limits on characters. But ya i think i missunderstood your question. Sorry...